# Bootstrap navbar with logo and text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a boostrap navbar with a small square logo on the left, text (company name) to the right, and then navbar on far right.  Here's code so far, I just can't figure out how to add the text.

When it goes down to XS, I need the logo and text to remain on the same line.  So, I made the logo image a full width transparent PNG (to hold the column in place) and tried to add text to the right of the logo (still over the transparent part) but I can't figure this out.

Any help would be great.  Here's code so far:

```html
    <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                
                                <div class="logo"><div style="height:50px; width:150px; position:absolute; border:solid 1px red;"></div><a href="<?php echo   site_url(); ?>/"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo_small.png"
                                class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                                
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 hidden-xs">

                    <!-- Navbar Start Here -->
                    <div role="navigation" class="navba-r navbar-default">
                        <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
                            </div>
                            <nav role="navigation" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left">
                                <ul class="navbar-nav nav aa">
                                    <li><a href="javascript:bookmarkscroll.scrollTo('company')">COMPANY</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="javascript:bookmarkscroll.scrollTo('people')">PEOPLE</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="javascript:bookmarkscroll.scrollTo('patient')">PATIENTS</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="javascript:bookmarkscroll.scrollTo('contact')">CONTACT</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Navbar End Here -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: any chance you can throw together a jsfiddle with this? Could be any number of things but one workaround may be to make it a part of the navigation menu, but rather than text place the logo. Otherwise inspect the element with the browser and tweak the margins to see if that aligns it.

Answer (score 7):

I put together a fiddle for you. I included the logo and title inside the nav. The key was adding the class `pull-left` to the href around the image.

https://jsfiddle.net/msm6jozL/7/

```
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="logo pull-left" href="#"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x30"></a>
        <span class="name pull-left">COMPANY NAME</span>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">COMPANY</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">PEOPLE</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">PATIENTS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>


.logo {
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}

.name {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
```